# Navbar component not loading with react and react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm just trying to load the react-bootstrap component  , and it doesn't seem to be loading. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I have installed react-bootstrap and bootstrap. I'm trying to wrap the  and export it to App.js

Here is my Navbar component and App.js respectively:

```
import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Component } from 'react';

class NavigationBar extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Navbar>
                hello
            </Navbar>
        )
    }
}

export default NavigationBar;

import React from 'react';
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar.js'
import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">

    <NavigationBar></NavigationBar>


      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you import ```bootstrap.css```?

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington, Yes, I did import it.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line => import React, { Component } from 'react';

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

class NavigationBar extends Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <Navbar>
          home
        </Navbar>
      )
    }
}

export default NavigationBar;
```